# Find the number code in the picture

Tags: visual

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [hyper-modern art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyper-modern%20is%3Aquestion)

---

The two friends in the gallery of hyper-modern art are moving on to the next room.

*"My head still aches from the colourful pixels under this microscope. Could we take a little rest please?"*

"Sure. Let's sit down here for a moment and rest our eyes on this rather simple black and white painting. It's somehow peaceful, don't you think?"

*"Hmm, sort of. What is it called?"*

"What would you call it?"

*"Not sure. Maybe  `Autumn storm in hiragana` ?"*

"Good one! No, it is actually called: `The code to the next room.`"

*"Really? I wonder if it really is that."*

"Of course it is! Have you forgotten how hyper-modern art works? In fact, we can only get into the next room if we enter the code into the number pad over there, see? Unfortunately, our HUD does not work in this room, so we'll have to figure it out ourselves..."

---

[image: Code]

---

> The goal of this puzzle is to derive the number code from the picture and describe how it can be gained. The story text is just flavour. The puzzle can be solved from the image alone and it could be solved from a printed version of that image.

There is a unique solution, so please don't answer with "I can see xy"-type answers. The solution has to contain **both** the number **code** *and* technique how to find it.

Comment: If required, I can provide a link to this image in a vector-format (EMF). Let me know..

Comment: Nobody having an idea for that? Or is anybody working on it? It's not a too hard puzzle...

Comment: I look at it with fresh eyes each day, and I don't have any ideas. It feels very difficult. There's gotta be some method of moving and turning the pieces in order to turn them into a coherent number, but it hasn't occured to me yet.

Comment: You're obviously more skilled with whatever tool it is you use to create these masterpieces.  What app do you use to make these?

Comment: I often draw my puzzles with Corel Draw.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the answer is:

> 1607852

The method used is:

> There are two of every shape in the image. If you imagine that these are the locations of the shape at times 1 and 2, then you can determine the position at time 3 (actually there are two possibilities depending on which way round you number the two shown shapes). By following the trajectory of all shapes and superimposing their end positions you get the answer.

Sorry if I've got this wrong - I didn't have a computer or printer, so I've tried to solve it with pen and paper!

My working (first attempt):

> [image]

My working (second attempt and I've still made a small mistake somewhere):

> [image: Working from second attempt]

Edit by puzzle author: The following images show the parts and solution as colourized bitmaps:

> [image: PArts] 
>  [image: Solution]

Comment: nice! now that i see the answer, it doesn't seem all that hard! haha! funny how that works.

Comment: I'm travelling and will check again later,but the method is definitely correct. Well done.

Comment: I've unaccepted the answer, as the actual number is not yet correct. The method, however, is. So I'll wait until the correct number is posted. (It's 7 digits and your last 4 are correct. As is one of the first two.) BTW, there is *hint* in the image (i.e. it's puzzle tiles) too. Bonus, if you can find/name it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I still made a mistake somewhere the second time around, and I hadn't spotted that some of the pieces are fixed (or move at speed zero?)  Thanks for a fun puzzle!

Comment: Re-accepted after verification of the number. Yes, the two "stationary" (and hence single) parts were the hint I was speaking of.